# Hibernate Annotation on parent fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class that is a POJO with no special Hibernate annotations or information, like so:

```
public class Parent{
   Long id;
   String foo;
   String bar;
   /* ... getters and setters, toString(), etc... */
}
```

I would like to create a child class that has the Hibernate annotations on it.  The idea is that the first class will not have any dependencies on it, and the second will have all of the JPA/Hibernate specific stuff.  How can I do that without re-creating all the fields in the parent?  I would like to put Hibernate annotations on the class

```
@Entity
public class PersistentChild extends Parent{
  // ????
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation on the POJO, then add the other annotations, as it were a normal JPA entity. But in this case, the annotations will only affect the entity classes, which are inheriting from it. Example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Parent implements Serializable {
     @Id
     Long id;
     @Column(name = "foo", required = true)
     String foo;
     @Column(name = "bar", required = false)
     String bar;
     /* ... getters and setters, toString(), etc... */
}
```

If you really do not want to modify the superclass, you can use a mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <mapped-superclass class="Parent">
        <!-- add your mapping here -->
    </mapped-superclass>
</entity-mappings>
```

---

#### Alternative approach

Also, you can just add the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation, then define all properties like this:

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "foo", column=@Column(name = "foo", required = true)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "bar", column=@Column(name = "bar", required = false))
})
public class PersistentChild extends Parent {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
}
```

Comment: I like your alternate approach and will give that a shot.  That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I added an edit to your `alternative approach` because it worked like I wanted it to.

Comment: Doesn't adding the @MappedSuperclass annotation to the parent create the JPA dependency that OP was trying to avoid?

Comment: Well, it does make the JPA API a compile time dependency. But AFAIK this is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to externalize the mapping you have to use xml-mapping file.

Comment: Not quite, I can use the AttributeOverrides and AssociationOverrides.

Comment: errm no you cannot use AttributeOverrides etc without making the parent class an Entity and you can only do that by either adding an annotation to the Parent class (which you don't want to do), or you use XML as this answer says so no idea why someone downvoted it.